# Is there any way to backup TDE enable Azure DB(Managed Instance)

Tags: database-backups, tde, azure-sql-managed-instance

Our requirement is to manual back up of Azure DB(MI) when an event is triggered. This db is TDE enabled. I cannot decrypt and take manual backup as decrypting db takes long time. Is there any way to back up of db (export to Azure storage) manually and export it to Azure storage?

Answer (score 0):

If you say that removing the TDE takes too much time and it's not an option, then you can export the database to a BACPAC file.
If removing TDE takes too much time I can assume that the DB has a considerable size and in that case I advise to use SQLPackage running on a Azure VM on the same region where the MI is.
Be alerted that the BACPAC file is not encrypted.

But if you need a backup file, then you need to remove the TDE or copy the database and on the copy remove the TDE, then execute the backup.

Answer (score 0):

You could switch from service-managed TDE to [customer-managed TDE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/transparent-data-encryption-byok-azure-sql), with protector key kept in Azure Key Vault. You can take copy-only backups of your database(s) as long as they are encrypted with that key. Please be aware that you need to keep the protector key(s) as long as you keep backup files. To restore such a backup to the same or some other managed instance, you need to provide access to the key to the destination instance first.